# Elementary solution to differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$E$ is a normed vector space of finite dimension. Let $H \in E$ and $A$ an endomorphism of $E$.
I'm looking for a solution to the following equation
$$f'(t)=\exp(tA)H, \text{    } f(0)=0$$
Where $f$ is a map from $\mathbb R$ to $E$
I've seen much handwaving around where people suggest integrating term by term the series expansion
$$\exp(tA)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}A^n$$ But it is not at all clear to me how to justify that, I only know of the theorem of integration term by term for uniformly convergent (or at best dominated, i.e the Dominated Convergence Theorem) for real valued functions, and I don't see how to generalize these two results or even if there is a simpler argument I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The series is uniformly convergent for $t$ in any bounded interval, using the bound $\|A\|^n \le \|A\|^n$ (where $\| \cdot \|$ is the operator norm).

Comment: Can I do it without directly using term-by-term integration of vector-valued functions? Because that's my original concern

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, $f(t) = A^{-1} (e^{tA}-I) H$.  If not, it's a bit trickier, but you could note that
$g(z) = z^{-1} (e^{tz} - 1)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$ and define $f(t) = g(A) H$ using the holomorphic functional calculus.